# how to make user_signed_in work (multiple users) -- devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In total there are two types of models: one is called business, another is user, inside user I also have an admin boolean attribute. I generated two devise for them. However, when I use

```
 <% if business.signed_in? %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'business', current_business.company_name %>
    <% elsif user.signed_in? %>
         <% if current_user.admin?  %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'approved', true %>
         <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

in a particular view, say this view corresponds to a controller 'object', both `business_signed_in?` and `user_signed_in?` are not working (No method error). Can anyone help me with how to modify my controller to make the view work? Only the admin and business can access this particular view, but not other users.

Thanks!

Comment: try to use 'user_signed_in?' instead of 'user.signed_in?'

Answer (score 1):

Devise user signed_in or not is a redundant/unnecessary check. Anyway you are using the `current_user` method later so check that directly, store it in a variable and check whether it is `present?`. If signed_in, it will return user object else nil. You can then use this the following way.

```
<% if (business = current_business).present? %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'business', business.company_name %>
<% elsif (user = current_user).present? && user.admin? %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'approved', true %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanx @GertArnold, i edited the answer and explained it.

Comment: Thanks very much! It indeed works, however I am not sure why attribute 'business' and 'approved' are not saved? Do I need to specify anything in controller to save the data in hidden_field_tag as well? (Both `business`and `approved` are attributes of this model and I want to save the value written in hidden_field_tag to them when creating a new model.)

Comment: Syntax wise they look good, u need to debug at the controller whether u receive those values in params on submit or not, are they permitted if u using strong params, etc..there can be multiple reasons